# C# programmatically form to image

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

there are two forms in my program, `Form A` and `Form B`.

There is a button in `Form A` which can take a screen shot of `Form B`(without start `Form B`).

However, the components of `Form B` are created in `Form_Load` function.

I use the below code to take a screen shot of `Form B` but it only generate a empty `Form B` image without any component of its.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1280, 720);
formB.ManualLoad();
formB.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720));
b.Save("D:\\Test.bmp");
```

The Manuaload() function is in below.

```
public void ManualLoad()
{
    formB_Load(null, null);
    formB_Resize(null, null);
    Invalidate();
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: form is not shown so the form's `Paint` event is not triggered and the controls are not drawn. I'm not sure you can take screenshot without showing form...

Comment: It won't as the Form is not drawn. You have to show the form in order to take a screenshot

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to Form B? Else I would suggest just showing it and then make a printscreen

Comment: Tkank you. I weill research that Is is possible to call `Paint` manually or I must show the `Form B` in order to take a snap shot.

Comment: The user doesn't want to see `Form B` flashed on the screen due to take a snapshot and close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

formB_Load(null, null);
and
formB_Resize(null, null);

ints even hanler load and resize event's

next code will be to work

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1280, 720);
var form = new formB();
form.Visible = false;
form.Show();
form.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720));
form.Close();
b.Save("D:\\Test.bmp");
```